# Tomcat can't write to the filesystem on aws EB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8, thingworx

I'm deploying a war file (Thingworx Iot Software) on tomcat with elastic beanstalk. The software is trying to create some folders/files under Several folders (at server root) I've given tomcat permissions to write to.

```
drwxrwxr-x   3 tomcat tomcat  4096 Jan 12 22:41 ThingworxBackupStorage
drwxr-xr-x   2 tomcat tomcat  4096 Jan 13 20:47 ThingworxPlatform
drwxrwxr-x   9 tomcat tomcat  4096 Jan 12 22:41 ThingworxStorage
```

Heres the error I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: THINGWORX WARNING: could not create directory: /ThingworxStorage/database
    at com.thingworx.common.utils.PathUtilities.createPath(PathUtilities.java:39)
    at com.thingworx.system.configuration.PlatformSettings.prepareLocation(PlatformSettings.java:302)
    ... 20 more
```

I'm running Java 8 and Tomcat 8 on an AWS EB setup.

Seams like it should just be a simple permissions thing, but from what I can tell I've already done all that properly. What am I missing?

Comment: Is `/ThingworxStorage` hanging directly off `/`?  In other words, does absolute path `/ThingworxStorage` exist?

Comment: Yep, all the folders I need to write to are at root. I've updated the answer to clarify that.